# Optimize NSRegularExpression performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

My app has a feed with posts that can contain URL's, #hashtags and @mentions. I display them using a pod called [ActiveLabel](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift). This pod does a good job, but my feed slightly lags when scrolling. My feed is a `UICollectionView`, and the cell generation is slightly lagging. I profiled my app when scrolling, and analysed the lag spikes. The lag is *almost* unnoticeable, but it annoys me.

[image: Lag]

As you can see, the main offender is the NSRegularExpression search.

I tried to optimize this slightly by disabling data detection when there is no instances of the data type, using `.contains()`. This made it marginally faster, but the lag spikes remains.

```
let enabledTypes:[ActiveType] = {
        var types = [ActiveType]()
        if ad.caption.current.string.contains("#") { types.append(.hashtag) }
        if ad.caption.current.string.contains("@") { types.append(.mention) }
        if ad.caption.current.string.contains("://") { types.append(.url) }
        if ad.caption.canExpand { types.append(seeMore) }
        return types
    }()
label.enabledTypes = enabledTypes
```

I also followed every step in [this article](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5#.7jek7msnv), which slighty helped, but not enough. So I need to fix the regex.

The regex statements `ActiveLabel` uses is

```
static let hashtagPattern = "(?:^|\\s|$)#[\\p{L}0-9_]*"
static let mentionPattern = "(?:^|\\s|$|[.])@[\\p{L}0-9_]*"
static let urlPattern = "(^|[\\s.:;?\\-\\]<\\(])" + "((https?://|www\\.|pic\\.)[-\\w;/?:@&=+$\\|\\_.!~*\\|'()\\[\\]%#,☺]+[\\w/#](\\(\\))?)" + "(?=$|[\\s',\\|\\(\\).:;?\\-\\[\\]>\\)])"
```

and it uses them with

```
 static func getElements(from text: String, with pattern: String, range: NSRange) -> [NSTextCheckingResult]{
    guard let elementRegex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [.caseInsensitive]) else { return [] }
    return elementRegex.matches(in: text, options: [], range: range)
}
```

Is searched around for other regexes to detect hashtags and mentions, but I didn't find anything that made a difference.

I tried to layout the label on a background thread, but that obviously crashed because UI doesn't like being done on a background thread. I *could* rewrite ActiveLabel to work mainly on background threads where I can and use callbacks instead of return types, but I'd like to avoid that.

Some samples of strings that I detect data on:

> "Arnie says, Aspen. Str. Small. Varm og god jakke. Veldig fin på! Fremstår ubrukt. Kun brukt et par ganger, rett og slett fordi jeg har alt for mange jakker #urban #arnie #says #aspen #ubrukt"
>
> "Skjorte pent brukt i organisk bomull fra tom tailor originalpris 300kr #organisk #bomullsjorte #bomull #flower #floral"
>
> "Jean Paul genser i 100% ull, pent brukt✨ er i str.m, men veldig liten, passer xs-s! \n #jeanpaul #genser #classy #litebrukt #brun #ull"

As you can see, our users mainly hashtag stuff, so that one is the most important one.

**Is there any way I can improve either `NSRegularExpression` or the regex statements to avoid the performance hit?**

Comment: Your `urlPattern` pattern is not optimal. It may cause slowdown when matching long strings that do not match the pattern. Also, `"(?:^|\\s|$)#[\\p{L}0-9_]*"` will match a string like `#`. I think you can use `static let hashtagPattern = "\\B#[\\p{L}0-9_]+"` and `static let mentionPattern = "\\B@[\\p{L}0-9_]+"`.

Comment: Would it be helpful to use `NSDataDetector` instead?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The ActiveLabel framework filters for length in another location, but I will test with your expression instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As @raidfive suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41705845/957768), most likely your best course of action here is to create one or more `NSRegularExpression` instances ahead of time and reuse them whenever needed.

Note that since it's the creation/compiling of regexes that makes the biggest difference in your time profile (at least, in as much of the time profile as you've shared), caching regexes may win you back enough performance that you no longer need your intermediate optimization of enabling only the detection elements you need. In that case, you need only one regex (representing detection of all possible element types), so caching/reuse is easy.

Note furthermore that your intermediate "optimization" may not actually improve performance to begin with — it might even harm performance. Matching a regex, however complicated, requires searching the entire string in its entirety (roughly) once. Trying to decide which element types to detect means searching the string multiple times — once for each `contains("#")` (etc) test, then once more to evaluate the string against the regex. Repeated string searches might well cost more than the compilation of a single regex.

If you find after implementing the single cached universal regex that you're still (somehow) hamstrung on regex performance, you can cache multiple regexes, one for each search scenario you're processing. The combinatorics presumably work out such that you still have far fewer different regexes than you have strings to process, so if you compile them all before the user even starts scrolling, you're not paying the time cost of compiling them during scrolling. Per the previous paragraph, though, this only makes sense if you have a cheap (i.e. not string search) way of detecting which regex you need for each string.

Comment: Your and @raidfive's answers are correct. I will accept your as you put more effort into it. It was true that `.contains` was a slowdown. I also made a static NSRegularExpression instance, which helped a lot. Turns out that its allocation is expensive. Tweaking ActiveLabel to work with callbacks on a background thread did not improve it enough, so I reverted that change. I still get tiny lag spikes, but its from AlamofireImage and SwiftyJSON now.. Yelp.

Answer (score 4):

You could try creating and storing the `NSRegularExpression` instances in a variable (class or instance) so you're only creating them once.

Comment: `NSRegularExpression` needs to be set up as its initialised, and doesn't allow configuration after the initial initialisation :/

Comment: What do you need to configure after initialization? Looking at your code examples, it seems like you just need three instances of `NSRegularExpression` with their associated patterns.

Example: `static let hashtagRegex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?:^|\\s|$)#[\\p{L}0-9_]*", options: [.caseInsensitive])`

Comment: Good point, I did not think of that. In my head I thought i needed to init it with the string i wanted to match.

Comment: You're probably also wasting performance trying to decide which regex you need, so you might only need to cache a single one. (Note [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41706634/957768) — sorry to steal your thunder @raidfive but it was too much to fit in a comment.)